Не могу понять в чём ошибка в ассемблерной вставке
Написал ассеблерную вставку в си, но выдает такую ошибку: "недопустимый тип операнда" в этих строчках: "je input_success". Кто может подсказать в чём проблема? Использую VS2022
int inputNumber() {
int a;
int input_success = 0;

const char input_msg[] = "Введите число: ";
const char error_msg[] = "\nНекорректный ввод! Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова: ";

__asm {
input_loop:
    ; Попытка считать число
        lea edx, input_msg
        lea edx, a
        xor eax, eax
        call scanf
        cmp eax, 1
        jne input_error

        ; Проверка наличия лишних символов в буфере ввода
        xor ecx, ecx
        check_extra_chars :
    call getchar
        cmp eax, '\n'
        je input_success // здесь
        cmp eax, EOF
        je input_success // и здесь
        jmp check_extra_chars

        input_error :
    lea edx, error_msg
        xor eax, eax
        call printf
        jmp clear_input_buffer

    input_success :
    mov DWORD PTR[input_success], 1
        jmp clear_input_buffer

        clear_input_buffer :
    xor eax, eax
        clear_input_char :
    call getchar
        cmp eax, '\n'
        je input_loop
        cmp eax, EOF
        je input_loop
        jmp clear_input_char
}

return a;

}

возможные дубликаты

Что-то связано с именем метки, похоже. Я ее заменил на input_s:, и все прошло...

Между именем метки и двоеточием не должно быть пробела, т.е. правильно input_success:. Это касается и остальных меток.
